# файловая структура

Tags: java

```
public abstract class FileSysItem {
    private Directory parent;
    private String name;
    private Double size;

    public FileSysItem(String name, Double size, Directory parent) {
        this.name = name;
        this.size = size;
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public FileSysItem(String name, Directory parent) {
        this(name, 0.0, parent);
    }

    void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public Double getSize() {
        return size;
    }
}

public class Files extends FileSysItem {
    public Files(String name, Double size, Directory parent) {
        super(name, size, parent);
    }

    public Files(String name, Directory parent) {
        super(name, 0.0, parent);
    }
}

public class Directory extends FileSysItem {
    ArrayList<FileSysItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

    public Directory(String name, Directory parent) {
        super(name, 0.0, parent);
    }

    public int size() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public FileSysItem set(int index, FileSysItem element) {
        return items.set(index, element);
    }

    public FileSysItem get(int index) {
        return items.get(index);
    }

    public FileSysItem add(FileSysItem... fileSysItem) {
        for (int i = 0; i < fileSysItem.length; i++) {
            items.add(fileSysItem[i]);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public FileSysItem remove(int index) {
        return items.remove(index);
    }

    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        return items.remove(o);
    }

    public void clear() {
        items.clear();
    }

}
```

Создал классы для описания файловой структуры.Но,не могу никак понять как сделать,чтобы каталоги представляли собой **несвязанный список**,а файлы **очередь на основе массива**.И Все ли классы я создал или еще нужны?И Заранее спасибо

Comment: Что такое «**несвязанный список**»? Попробуйте расписать подробнее какой цели Вы хотите добиться.

Comment: Нужно расписать классы иллюстрирующие двухуровневую файловую структуру .Для описания каталогов использовать список ,а для файлов очередь на основе массива